# Rooted Nexus 4 wants to update

Tags: nexus-4, device-firmware, root-access

I got the problem that my Nexus sometimes wants to update to 4.2.1 although the system update menu says the newest version is installed (4.2).

When I let the update do what it wants and it reboots, it fails at the recovery system with "apply patch check *something*".

Only thing I've done to my Nexus so far is rooting it.

Comment: The version check from the System Update menu, seems a little bit "off", whether that's a minor bug, not sure...4.2.1 is fairly recent, now that 4.2.2 is out - FYI! The apply patch check something is down to either boot-loader is locked, or that there is not enough space...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a rooted Nexus 4 will be able to update automatically. So you might have to turn auto update off. Rooting will void its warranty.

But not to worry, rooting is good. Some how you can flash an updated version of stock ROM manually to your device.

Comment: Rooting does not void the warranty in the EU :)

Comment: I saw stock ROMs available for the Nexus 7 but I cannot find them for the Nexus 4.

Comment: This thread will help you. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2010887 .

Comment: @Izzy, I am sorry I didn't know that. :)

Comment: That's why I mentioned it -- no need to be sorry, just need to remember ;)

Comment: Ok thank you for the threadlink. I'm actually at xda forums but did not know I have to flash it manually due to rooting.

Comment: According to @Izzy's comment if you are from EU, then you don't have to.

Comment: Try @t0mm13b's steps as well. May be that could be a possible reason

Answer (score 0):

The OTA update won't work with root. You can manually flash a ROM to your device.  You can get stock (factory) ROMs from Google *https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images*, Nexus 4 is about 1/3rd down the page. You can also go to XDA forums and get a custom ROM *http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4*, main forum page for Nexus 4.

---

The other way would be to use Wugfresh Toolkit for Nexus to relock/unroot device,  to be able to get OTAs.

Forum link: *http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/orig-development/toolkit-wugs-nexus-root-toolkit-v1-8-2-t2015469*

Wugfresh Toolkit download: *http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/*

READ EVERYTHING AND MAKE A BACKUP BEFORE DOING ANYTHING!!!!